# Javascript button event to trigger a form based calculation is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sorry that a few variables are in dutch, I could change it to English if necessary.

This script should calculate the fee of the textbox "kosten".
The fee is calculated by applying a percentage, this is made possible by selecting a number in the combobox.

For some reason, when clicking on the button "totaalfooi" to start the calculation and get a result, nothing happends..

Javascript code:

```js
function berekenkosten() {
    var inputkosten = document.getElementById('kosten');
    var kosten = 0;
    if (inputkosten.value != "") {
        kosten = parseInt(inputkosten.value);
    }
    return kosten;
}
var procentfooi = new Array();
procentfooi["1"]=2;
procentfooi["2"]=2.5;
procentfooi["3"]=3;
procentfooi["4"]=3.5;
procentfooi["5"]=4;

function berekenfooi () {
    var berekenfooi=0;
    for(var i = 0;
        i < procentfooi.length; i++) {
        if(procentfooi[i].checked) {
            berekenfooi=procentfooi[procentfooi[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return berekenfooi;
}

function berekentotaal () {
    var totaalfooi = (berekenfooi/100) * berekenkosten();
    document.getElementById(totaalfooi).innerHTML = "Totale fooi bedraagt: $" + totaalfooi;

}
```

```html
<div id="JSfee">Totale kosten <input type="text" id="kosten"> <br><br> Graad van tevredenheid op 5
    <select>
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="bereken" onclick="berekentotaal()">
    <br><br>
    <div id="totaalfooi">
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: That's just because of the initial `<script>` tag.

Comment: i strongly recommand using .addEventlistener instead of adding it to you html markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
function berekenkosten() {
    var inputkosten = document.getElementById('kosten');
    var kosten = 0;
    if (inputkosten.value != "") {
        kosten = parseInt(inputkosten.value);
    }
    return kosten;
}

function berekenfooi() {
    var berekenfooi = 0,
    seloption = document.querySelector('#JSfee select'),
    procentfooi = [2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4]
    return procentfooi[seloption.selectedIndex];
}

function berekentotaal() {
    var totaalfooi = (berekenfooi()/100) * berekenkosten();
    document.getElementById('totaalfooi').innerHTML = "Totale fooi bedraagt: $" + totaalfooi;
}
```

You have some syntactical errors in your berekentotaal function, `berekenfooi` is a function not an object therefore must be called with () and getElementById requires an string to find the element. With this solution you don't need the values in the select so they could be written like this

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you devconcept, this fixed my problem!

Comment: There is !no! reason to have values in the options as well as an array to store the percent values.  Also this takes into account changes to the HTML which were not shown nor is it a working snippet...

Comment: @VulgarBinary looking to the original code i realized what MarnikBruyndonckx was attempting to do. He also used an array to store those values. This is why i discarded the values stored in the DOM. I guess I should update the answer to specify that there are no need for those values anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You had multiple syntax errors which are fixed in the example below.

You cannot have variables named the same as functions, these will overwrite each other.

You cannot treat a function variable as a value type, you have to invoke the function.

getElementById takes a string argument, you were passing "variables" that were unassigned.

You needed an ID on your select, to then choose it by.  You were iterating over an array which was not bound to the DOM.

A few other modifications, this works in the snippet and if you copy it over, should work to fix your problems.

```js
            function berekenkosten() {
                var inputkosten = document.getElementById('kosten');
                var kosten = 0;
                if (inputkosten.value != "") {
                    kosten = parseInt(inputkosten.value);
                }
                return kosten;
            }

            function berekenfooi () {
                var procentfooi = document.getElementById("procentfooi");
                var percentToReturn=procentfooi.options[procentfooi.selectedIndex].value;
                console.log(percentToReturn + " with " + procentfooi.length);
                return parseFloat(percentToReturn);
            }

            function berekentotaal () {
                var totaalfooi = (berekenfooi()/100) * berekenkosten();
                document.getElementById("totaalfooi").innerHTML = "Totale fooi bedraagt: $" + totaalfooi;

            }
```

```html
<div id="JSfee">Totale kosten <input type="text" id="kosten"> <br><br> Graad van tevredenheid op 5
    <select id='procentfooi'>
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="bereken" onclick="berekentotaal()">
    <br><br>
    <div id="totaalfooi">
        </div>


    </div>
```

Snippet results:

[image: Running this snippet gives you these results, and is working.]

Comment: Make your values of your options in HTML the values you want to apply as the percent.  There is no need to have a separate array to support this as well as values on the options.

Comment: Thank you for the modifications, but sadly there is still no result after clicking on the button.

Comment: Use my snippet in my answer.  It works.  Verified a dozen times.  If someone takes the time to copy your snippet and fix it, then use their snippet.  Chances are they took the time for a reason.... Just verified again in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.  This snippet below my answer works in all browsers.

Comment: I just added the image showing you how to run the snippet.  There were changes in both HTML and in the JavaScript.

Comment: Working fine for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming through your code, it seems that the problem lies in this line:

```
document.getElementById(totaalfooi).innerHTML = "Totale fooi bedraagt: $" + totaalfooi;
```

`totaalfooi` is a result of a calculation, so I guess you meant to pass the  string:

```
document.getElementById('totaalfooi').innerHTML = "Totale fooi bedraagt: $" + totaalfooi;
```

Comment: I've replaced the line, still no result.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in this line:
`var totaalfooi = (berekenfooi/100) * berekenkosten();`

You're dividing berekenfooi by 100, but berekenfooi is a function you define earlier, not a value.  So it should be:

`var totaalfooi = (berekenfooi()/100) * berekenkosten();`

Comment: I've replaced the line, still no result.